# Reddit comments labeled data-set for sentiment analysis?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I was searching for a Reddit comments data-set which is labeled into three classes: positive, negative and neutral to train a ML model. I can get labeled data for tweets, movie reviews but what about Reddit. Is there any credible source for it?

PS: I don't want to annotate the data myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reddit Comment Dataset Including Sentiment Data](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/59039y/updated_reddit_comment_dataset_up_to_201608/)